# read text file with phpexcel comma or tab delimiter

Tags: regex, preg-match, phpexcel

I have to read a text file with comma(,) or tab delimiter . if this not possible plz suggest me any way to read like reg exp or anything like that..
Here is the sample file

```
Transaction Date      Transaction Description      Transaction Debit Transaction Credit 
  18/03/2014,        'POS Transaction 7400000000',       212.00,         ' ',
  14/03/2014,        'POS Transaction 770000000',        202.95,         ' ',
  14/03/2014,        'POS Transaction 77631000000',      202.95,         ' ',
  14/03/2014,        'REV POS Purchase77100000000',       ' ',          202.95
  11/03/2014,        'MB - Qtel Hala TopUp 50109671 ,QTEL REF:QI3283',30.00 ' ',
  10/03/2014,        'MB - VODAFONERED35',               35.00,           ' ',
  08/03/2014,        'MB - Qtel Bill Payment 446748 , QTEL REF:QIB13295320',250.00,' ',
  03/03/2014,        'MB-Transfer from 100248417 to 100222077',   '5,000.00',   ' ',
  01/03/2014,        'POS Transaction 40501048',          207.85,    ' ',
  27/02/2014,        'TFR:000019-Payment - Automatic Loan Pymt W/D','2,880.00',' ',
  27/02/2014,        'TFR:000005-Payment - Automatic Loan Pymt W/D','2,771.00',' ',
  27/02/2014,        'ATM Withdraw 0058',                 '4,000.00',' ',
  27/02/2014,        'ATM Withdraw 0058',                 '5,000.00',' ',
  27/02/2014,        'MB-Transfer from 109812 to 10017',    ' ',     500.00
  27/02/2014,        'MB-Transfer from 10892 to 100417',    ' ',     500.00
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this to match all comma separated value and will ignore if comma is coming between the number

```
$f= file("statement.txt"); //if from text file

foreach($f as $dailystatmet)
{

         preg_match_all("/('?\d+,\d+\.\d+)?([a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|)[^,]+/",$dailystatmet,$matches);

        var_dump($matches);
}
```

or

```
$dailystatmet="18/03/2014,'POS Transaction 7400000000',212.00,' ', 14/03/2014";
preg_match_all("/('?\d+,\d+\.\d+)?([a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|)[^,]+/",$dailystatmet,$matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

Comment: For tab replace the comma with \t ie /('?\d+,\d+\.\d+)?([a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|)[^\t]+/